# mysql | select record from table where month and year is not current or employee id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have this query

```
SELECT E.employee_id FROM employee E
INNER JOIN timesheet T ON T.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id` AND DATE_FORMAT(T.`date_created`, '%Y-%m') != DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
WHERE T.`employee_id` NOT IN (1,2)
```

actually I am trying to get only employees whose ids are not listed in 1,2 and if `employee_id` is present for `1` or `2` then the month and year should not be the current month and year for that particular employee

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfa01/2)**

I am not sure if am doing it the right way.

Comment: Query in fiddle is correct. But not the one mentioned in question. Just add `distinct` to prevent duplication.

Comment: Btw, note that a function on a join condition precludes the use of an index on that condition. So, although it seems tedious, something like "where year <> year or month <> month " will actually be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you need an `or` relationship between your conditions, not an `and` relationship. Also, it's preferable to leave the `join` condition for joining and have all your "business" logic in the `where` clause - it makes your query easier to read:

```
SELECT     E.employee_id
FROM       employee E
INNER JOIN timesheet T ON T.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id` 
WHERE      T.`employee_id` NOT IN (1,2) OR -- Note the "OR" relationship
           DATE_FORMAT(T.`date_created`, '%Y-%m') != 
           DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: oops.. was missing the OR, i was using AND.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT E.employee_id FROM employee E
INNER JOIN timesheet T ON T.`employee_id` = E.`employee_id` 
WHERE T.`employee_id` NOT IN (1,2) OR (DATE_FORMAT(T.`date_created`, '%Y-%m') != DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m'))
```